# How to Count comma splitted values having value greater than 0 in pgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am using PostgreSQL and store values in the database as **comma split-ted**. Now I want to count all comma split-ted values where individual value is **greater than zero**.

How can I achieve it?

My db column values are looking like

```
0,120,0,0,118,0,0,128,0,123,0,0,0,125,0
192,193,196,195
192,193,196,1950,128,0,123,0,0,
```

What i tried is:

```
SELECT case when col='0' then 0 else array_length(regexp_split_to_array(replace(replace(col,'0,',''),',0',''), ','), 1) end 
FROM table
```

**Here problem is it replaces all 0 even it exist in any other value**

**Note:** I am using **PostgreSQL 8.4.2**

Comment: You should not store comma delimited values in the first place. If you can, fix your design.

Comment: At this stage i cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest() the values in the array (essentially converting it into a properly normalized model) and then you can correctly count them:

It's unclear to me if you want to count those non-zero values across all rows in the table or for each row.

To count that across all rows:

```
select count(*)
from the_table, 
     unnest(string_to_array(the_column, ',')) as x(v) 
where v::int > 0;
```

If you need to count them for each row, you can do that assuming you have a primary key (or unique) column in the table:

```
select id, count(*)
from the_table, 
     unnest(string_to_array(the_column, ',')) as x(v) 
where v::int > 0
group by id;
```

The above assumes there is a column `id` which is unique.

**Edit**

For old and unsupported Postgres versions you need to change that to:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select unnest(string_to_array(the_column, ',')) v
  from the_table
) t  
where v::int > 0
```

or

```
select id, count(*)
from (
  select id, unnest(string_to_array(the_column, ',')) v
  from the_table
) t
where v::int > 0
group by id;
```

Comment: function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level.............

Comment: @ImranQamer: then you are using an outdated Postgres version. It certainly works. See here: http://rextester.com/YLIU57870

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4.20  and now i cant change it, its being controlled by server management

Comment: @ImranQamer: you should have mentioned that in your question that you are using an outdated and unsupported version. See my edit, that should work in 8.4 as well

Answer (score 1):

This is such a bad database design.  But, here is one method using `length()`:

```
select (length(replace('[' || replace(col, ',', '][') || ']', '[0]', '')) -
        length(replace(replace('[' || replace(col, ',', '][') || ']', '[0]', ''), '[', '')) 
       )
```

The `replace()` is funky with just commas in this case.  Here is an example of the code working:

```
select replace('[' || replace(col, ',', '][') || ']', '[0]', ''),
       (length(replace('[' || replace(col, ',', '][') || ']', '[0]', '')) -
        length(replace(replace('[' || replace(col, ',', '][') || ']', '[0]', ''), '[', '')) 
       )
 from (select 'a,0,0,b'::text as col union all
       select '1,2,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1'::text) x
```

Comment: operator does not exist: text - text

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Of course not.  There should have been a `length()` in there.